# jquery form submit not working with multiple inputs (IE & Firefox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Probably simple but it's confusing me at the moment.

If you look at this jsfiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VNHx3/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

 <form id='adminForm'>
  <input type="text" />
  <!--<input type="password" />-->
 </form>      

 <script>
 $(document).ready( function(){
   $("#adminForm").submit(function() {
     alert('submit');
     return false;
   });

 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If i press ENTER to submit the form, it works fine and i get the alert. But if I then uncomment the other input and try it again, nothing happens. Doesn't make any difference which input is commented, it seems that in IE and Firefox it is only working when there is 1 input in the form instead of multiple ones... Whereas in Opera it works fine with multiple inputs.

Any clues?

Cheers.

Comment: thats not problem of jquery or inputs with multiple input you have to use submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, yeah you need submit button but if you don't want to show it you can either

```
<input type="submit" style="visibility:hidden;" />
```

or

```
<input type="submit" style="position:absolute;left:-9999px;width:1px;height:1px;" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try that earlier but did display:none instead of visibility, so assumed that wasn't the reason.